# Showing map markers by location in list outside map

Tags: javascript

I have a number of markers and I want to show the markers in a list outside of the map. How can this be achieved using javascript? I am new to Javascript so help is appreciated. Code I have currently below, this is all working as expected apart from listing the map marker information.

I idea is that a list will appear depending on the option chosen in the dropdown for counties.

```
//List of Counties
var counties = [{
    name: "Armagh",
    code: "am",
    zoom : 8,
    center: {
        lat: 54.274911,
        lng: -6.626583
    }
}, {
    name: "Cork",
    code: "c",
    zoom : 8,
    center: {
        lat: 51.904246,
        lng: -8.474038
    }
}];

//List of Practices
var practice = [{
    name: "Cross Veterinary Clinic",
    position: {
        lat: 54.07531,
        lng: -6.60590
    },
    code: "am",
    address: "8 Dundalk Road, Crossmaglen, Co. Armagh",
    vet: "Carol Peterson",
    programme: ['bvd', 'jd']
}, {
    name: "Keltic Veterinary",
    position: {
        lat: 52.35386,
        lng: -8.68204
    },
    code: "c",
    address: "Charleville Town Centre, Bakers Road, Charleville, Co. Cork",
    vet: "Gerald Gonzales",
    programme: ['cck', 'bvd']
}];


var countyselect = document.getElementById('county')
countyselect.addEventListener("change", onCountySelect); 



//render map


function initialize() {
    var options = {
        center: {
            lat: 53.2734,
            lng: -7.77832031
        },
        zoom: 6.5
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), options);
    marker = renderMarker();

}


function renderMarker() {
    for (var i = 0; i < practice.length; i++) {
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: practice[i].position,
            title: practice[i].name,
            map: map,
        });
        inforwindow(marker, map);
    }
}

function inforwindow(marker, map) {
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(); {
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(renderMarker) {
            infowindow.setContent(marker.getTitle());
            infowindow.open(map, marker);
        });
    }
}


 function onCountySelect() {
    let countySelect = document.getElementById("county");
     let selectedCounty = countySelect.options[countySelect.selectedIndex];
     let countyFound = (counties.find(({ name }) => name === selectedCounty.value));
    if (selectedCounty.value === "all") {
        map.setCenter({ lat: 53.2734, lng: -7.77832031 });
        map.setZoom(6.5);
    } else {
        map.setCenter(countyFound.center);
       map.setZoom(countyFound.zoom);
    }
 }


function resultsList() {
  if (selectedCounty.value === "all") {
  let countySelect = document.write(`<h3>${practice.name}</h3><p>${practice.address}</p><p>${practice.vet}</p>`);

  }
}
```

Comment: I assume you mean Google Maps but you'll need to include more detail in your question. What have you tried? Can you post your code?

Comment: Yes, apologies, I looking for help as to where to start, I was trying to use document.write to pull data from the array but it's not doing anything. I am very new to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure at all from your code what your plan is with markers, or whether you intend to make items in the list clickable so that they highlight a specific marker on the map. But in any case, here's code to do what you asked - to create a list of relevant practices when a county is selected. I've dropped in some hacky test HTML just as it's easier to test.

Hopefully this will get you on the right path.

A couple of notes - you have used the backtick, ie using ` and ${variable} approach to rendering some content - this may not work on older browsers directly.

Also, please excuse the mix of single and double quotes - that's a matter of taste but I didn't see the point in going back and changing everything you had done. Good luck!

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Map Thing</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <style type="text/css">

      * {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        box-sizing: border-box;
      }

      html, body {
        font-family: Helvetica;
        min-height: 100vh;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
      }

      #container {
        flex: 1;
        display: flex;
      }

      #options {
        flex: 1;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
      }

      #results {
        margin-top: 40px;
        padding: 40px;
      }

      .result {
        padding: 30px;
        border: 1px solid #ddd;
      }

      #map {
        flex: 3;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="container">
      <div id="options">
        <select id="county" name="county" value="">
          <option value="">Please choose</option>
          <option value="am">Armagh</option>
          <option value="c">Cork</option>
        </select>

        <div id="results"><!-- will be populated --></div>
      </div>
      <div id="map"></div>
    </div>

    <script>

      //List of Counties
      var counties = [{
        name: "Armagh",
        code: "am",
        zoom : 8,
        center: {
          lat: 54.274911,
          lng: -6.626583
        }
      }, {
        name: "Cork",
        code: "c",
        zoom : 8,
        center: {
          lat: 51.904246,
          lng: -8.474038
        }
      }];

      //List of Practices
      var practices = [{
        name: "Cross Veterinary Clinic",
        position: {
          lat: 54.07531,
          lng: -6.60590
        },
        code: "am",
        address: "8 Dundalk Road, Crossmaglen, Co. Armagh",
        vet: "Carol Peterson",
        programme: ['bvd', 'jd']
    }, {
        name: "Keltic Veterinary",
        position: {
            lat: 52.35386,
            lng: -8.68204
        },
        code: "c",
        address: "Charleville Town Centre, Bakers Road, Charleville, Co. Cork",
        vet: "Gerald Gonzales",
        programme: ['cck', 'bvd']
      }];

      function initialize() {
        var options = {
          center: {
            lat: 53.2734,
            lng: -7.77832031
          },
          zoom: 6.5
        };

        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), options);

        var countyselect = document.getElementById('county');
        countyselect.addEventListener('change', onCountySelect);

        renderMarkers();
      }


      function renderMarkers() {
        for (var i = 0; i < practices.length; i++) {
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: practices[i].position,
            title: practices[i].name,
            map: map,
          });
        }
      }

      function showInfoWindow(marker, map) {
        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
          infowindow.setContent(marker.getTitle());
          infowindow.open(map, marker);
        });
      }


      function onCountySelect() {
        var countySelect = document.getElementById("county");
        var countiesByCode = counties.map(function(c){
          return c.code;
        });
        var index = countiesByCode.indexOf(countySelect.value)

        if (index > -1) {
          var selectedCounty = counties[index];
          map.setCenter(selectedCounty.center);
          map.setZoom(selectedCounty.zoom);

          renderResultsList(selectedCounty);
        } else {
          map.setCenter({ lat: 53.2734, lng: -7.77832031 });
          map.setZoom(6.5);

          clearResultsList();
        }
      }

      function renderResultsList(selectedCounty) {
        var relevantPractices = practices.filter(function(p){
          return p.code === selectedCounty.code;
        });
        var resultsArea = document.getElementById("results");
        resultsArea.innerHTML = "";

        for(var i = 0; i < relevantPractices.length; i++) {
          var practice = relevantPractices[i];
          var div = document.createElement("div");
          div.className = "result";
          div.innerHTML = `<h3>${practice.name}</h3><p>${practice.address}</p><p>${practice.vet}</p>`;
          resultsArea.appendChild(div);
        }
      }

      function clearResultsList() {
        document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = "";
      }

    </script>

    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_KEY_HERE&callback=initialize"
    async defer></script>


  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This has been a huge help to me, I really appreciate it. Yes, my intention was that the marker would be clickable but your suggestion to make the list item clickable and then aminate that marker would be far better for the user I think - would this be relatively simple to add on at this stage in your opinion?  I have noted your comments regarding to compatibility with older browsers.

Comment: It isn't that hard to do, but I suggest you plan how it's going to work and maybe mock it up first. Then try some things and hit up Stack Overflow again if you get stuck. Learning does involve some pain, sadly ;) I'd be really grateful if you could accept my answer as the correct one

Comment: Appreciate your advice, I will give it a go and see what I can come up with...learning code is painful at the best of times but it will be worth it in the end as they say!